# Shiny renderTable with commas

Tags: r, shiny

In my shiny package, I have the following code:

```
output$growthTable <- renderTable({
  table <- makeTable()
  colnames(table) <- c("Year","BOY Balance", "Yearly Growth", "EOY Contribution", "EOY Balance")
  return(table)
}, include.rownames = FALSE)
```

How can I make the last 4 columns have commas in them. So for instance `10000` becomes `10,000`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you didn't provide a reproducible example here is a working demonstration of how to do it.  To my knowledge there is no means to specify number format with the `renderTable` statement so you must reformat your values.  The key is to use `format` or `prettyNum` with the `big.mark` option set.  A word of caution, however, this is converting your numeric values into characters.  It is recommended that you should do this formatting conversion once there will be no further processing of the values.

```
require(shiny)
data(iris)

runApp(
  list(
    ui = fluidPage(
      headerPanel('Print big numbers with comma'),
      mainPanel(
        tableOutput("table"))
    ),

    server = function(input, output) {

      makeTable <- reactive({
        iris[,1:4] <- iris[1:4] * 1000
        #iris[,1:4] <- sapply(iris[,1:4], FUN=function(x) format(x, big.mark=","))
        iris[,1:4] <- sapply(iris[,1:4], FUN=function(x) prettyNum(x, big.mark=","))
        iris
      })

      output$table <- renderTable({
        table <- makeTable()
        table
      }, include.rownames = FALSE)
    }
  )
)
```